# User is able to open the JavaFx desktop application more than once in a Windows machine

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX desktop application where the User is able to open the JavaFx desktop application more than once in a Windows machine. From Mac it cant be opened more than once.

The following code is used to launch the application:

```
Application.launch(ExampleApplication.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
```

Apart from JUnique library, is there any way to fix this issue ?
Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Application.launch() should only succeed once per a single application as per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-). In addition it solely manages the current application and doesn't return until the application exits. If you want to be able to run the application more than once I'd recommend creating a standalone launcher for your application which runs a java process, which in turn runs your application. This way each time the launcher is executed a unique process is started and invokes the application.

Comment: I dont want to open the application more than once. The issue is, in Windows it is getting opened more than once. How to avoid multiple instances of JavaFX application?

Comment: How do you start the application from Windows?

Comment: Application is an executable jar and will open on double click.

Comment: Considering main() contains Application.launch() only, it is not an issue with JavaFX. Try running from command line and see if it still starts two instances.

Comment: From different command prompt windows I can open the application jar  multiple times...But from same cmd prompt we cant run a jar, if another one is opened right.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have misunderstood the question. So you want to prevent the user from starting the application more than once? If so, here is an interesting discussion: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/83331/how-to-stop-opening-multiple-instance-for-a-jar-file